# Functions on a group. Functions of the inverse element.

Tags: group-theory, measure-theory, lie-groups

Consider a Lie group $G$ and a Hilbert space $\mathbb{V}$ equipped with a dot product $~~\langle~,~\rangle$.

Let ${^G{\cal{L}}}$ be a space of square-integrable functions mapping $G$ to $\mathbb{V}$:
$$
 {^G{\cal{L}}}=\left\{ f:~~ G\longrightarrow\mathbb{V}\qquad\Big{|}\quad  \int dg \langle f(g), f(g)\rangle < \infty     \right\}.
 $$

We can map each $ f$ to a function of the inverse argument:
$$
 f(x)\longmapsto\varphi(x)\equiv f(x^{-1})~,\quad x\in G \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad (*)
 $$
or, in short:
$$
 f\longmapsto\varphi\equiv f\circ\hat{\zeta}~,
 $$
where
$$
 \hat{\zeta} x\,=\,x^{-1}
 $$
is the inversion operation on $G$.

Doing this for all $f$, we obtain a new space of functions:
$$
 {\cal{L}}^{G}=\left\{~\varphi:~G\longrightarrow{\mathbb{V}}~~\Big{|}~~\varphi= f\circ\hat{\zeta}~,~~f\in{^G{\cal{L}}}
 \right\}~. \qquad\qquad\qquad (**)
 $$

To examine if $~^{G}{\cal{L}}$ and ${\cal{L}}^{G}$ are copies of the same functional space, check the square-integrability of the new functions:
$$
  \int dg \langle \varphi(g),\varphi(g)\rangle=\int d(g^{-1}) \langle \varphi(g^{-1}) , \varphi(g^{-1})\rangle=
  \int d(g^{-1}) \langle f(g),f(g)\rangle
 $$
For unimodular groups, the measure is invariant and $d(g^{-1}) = dg $, wherefrom
$$
  \int dg \langle \varphi(g),\varphi(g)\rangle=
  \int dg \langle f(g),f(g)\rangle < \infty~,
 $$
so the spaces  $^{G}{\cal{L}}$ and ${\cal{L}}^{G}$ coincide.

For what nonunimodular groups would this outcome stay valid?

Say, for compact ones? For locally compact ones?

PS.

I understand that, by Haar's theorem, if a group is locally compact (i.e. if its identity element has a compact neighborhood), then it admits a unique left-invariant and a unique right-invariant measure (unique -- up to multiplication by a positive constant). Under the transformation $g\to g^{-1}$, a left-invariant measure transforms into a right-invariant one, and vice versa. Can this fact be somehow employed here?

Comment: Your argument works exactly as written for locally compact unimodular  topological groups. Beyond that, it seems like the definition of ${}^G\mathcal{L}$ would have to be made more precise, since since the existence / uniqueness up to scaling of the left Haar measure is not assured.

Comment: Suppose the group is locally compact, but not unimodular. What should be changed in my definition of $^G{\cal{L}}$ ?

Comment: The definition of ${}^G\mathcal{L}$ would still make sense in that case, but the result would no longer hold, since inversion need not map ${}^G\mathcal{L}$ into $\mathcal{L}^g$ when the modular function is unbounded.

Comment: @Kajelad Could you please help me understand your second comment? Why do you say that without unimodularity $^G{\cal{L}}$ will not be mapped into ${\cal{L}}^G$ ? By eqn (*), I map each function $f\in~^G{\cal{L}}$ to a corresponding $\varphi$. Then, by definition, ${\cal{L}}^G$ comprises all these $\varphi$. I am not sure if this gonna be a space of square-integrable functions -- but it should, at least, be a linear space, should it not? Or am I missing something?

Comment: My mistake; I mean to write that inversion need not map ${}^G\mathcal{L}$ into itself, and so ${}^G\mathcal{L}$ and $\mathcal{L}^G$ may differ when the modular function is not identically one.